# jquery .on function?

Tags: jquery, html

i have 2 lines jquery. first line is adding event on "myLink" and second line adding class "myLink" on "#another" but event is not working in second one but when i am using .live method then it is wokring. jquery introduce .on method in its 1.7 version. i want to do that it by .in function is this possible.

```
$(function(){

    $("a.myLink").on('click', function() { alert( 'Click!' ); } );

    $("a#another").addClass( "myLink" );
})



<a class="myLink">A link!</a>
<a id="another">Another link!</a>
```

Comment: Before you use `on`, do some study on *event delegation* and then read the docs. It's an important technique to understand in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wrote a primer on using `.on()` to replace `.live()` and explained both the static form of `.on()` (which you are using) and the dynamic form of `.on()` (which you need to be using).  That primer from earlier today is here: [Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409) which contains a lot more of the details.

You need to use something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "a.myLink" function() { alert( 'Click!' ); } );
```

or, even better use a static ancestor of your dynamic links instead of `document` (which I will assume here is an object `#container` as this will give better performance like this:

```
$("#container").on('click', "a.myLink" function() { alert( 'Click!' ); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

`$(document).on('click', 'a.mylink', function() { alert( 'Click!' ); } );`

Comment: Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ )

Answer (score 1):

Change this -

```
$("a.myLink").on('click', function() { alert( 'Click!' ); } );
```

to this -

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.myLink', function(){ alert( 'Click!' ); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clue is that it works with the live method.  It works then because you are adding the class to '#another' after already setting the event.  So you either have to use the live method or switch the order so that the class is added to 'another' first.