# updating quantity using a generated form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function for updating the total price when a user updates the quantity of a product. When the form is generated, the total doesn't update the total, but when i refresh the page, it works. I think i need to use the .on function, but I'm not sure.

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(event){
    var total = parseFloat($('#total').text());
    var newTotal = 0;
    var id = this.id.replace('qty-','');
    var qty = $('#qty-'+id).val();

    $('ol li').each(function(idx, li){
        var lId = li.id.replace('cart-','');
        var price = $('#price-'+lId).text();
        var lQty = $('#qty-'+lId).val();
        newTotal += parseFloat(price) * parseFloat(lQty);
    }); 

    $('#total').html(newTotal.toFixed(2));

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "resources/changeQty.php",
        data:{ id: id, qty: qty },
        cache: false,
    });

});
```

The code for the textfield is this:

```
<input type="text" name="newQty" id="qty-'.$productId.'" class="qty" size="2" maxlength="3" value="1" />
```

Comment: You are doing all stuff on key up that's why...so use The Same logic inside .ready function...so it will work when page loads

Comment: i do not understand what you mean, sorry im quite new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

If the database gets updated correctly, the problem is in the javascript price calculation (the middle section).

You should also post the section with the `#total` element, but my guess would be that this is not correct:

```
$('#total').html(newTotal.toFixed(2));
```

If `#total` is an input, you should replace it with:

```
$('#total').val(newTotal.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: this is that total looks like:
<p><strong> Total:</strong> &pound;<span id="total"><?php echo $total ?></span></a></p>

edit: i tried val, but it didnt update the total

Comment: @rob Does it get set to `0` when you change a quantity?

Comment: when i used val, it didnt change the the total

Comment: @rob No, I mean with your original code. `val()` is not going to work if your element is not an `input` or something similar.

Comment: When the form is generated on the fly, nothing happens, when i refresh and the form is created by the php, it make the total 0, orjust removes the price of the item off the total price

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the keyup function, i used the .on function as suggested by "Peeyush". After look at this post: 
[Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409)

i changed this:

```
$('.qty').keyup(function(event){});
```

to this:

```
$('#mainCart').on("keyup",".qty",function(e){});
```

"keyup" is the trigger event
".qty" is the slector, the thing that triggers the event, in this case "keyup"
the function is what i want to happen when someone presses a key in ".qty".

Sorry if thats not very well explained