# Dynamically add input fields when needed

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, input, addition

I'm trying to add extra input fields to my HTML form as they are needed. Here's my code:

### My code

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var i = $('.form-inputs input').size() + 1;

    $('.section-topic-field').last().bind('keyup', function(e) {
        if($(this).val() != "") {
            var html_new_field = '<input name="txtTopicName' + i + '" class="section-topic-field" type="text" onfocus="this.value=\'\'" placeholder="topic name #' + i + '" /><br />';

            $('.form-inputs').append($(html_new_field).fadeIn('slow'));

            i++;
        }
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
        <input name="txtSection" type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" placeholder="sections"/><br/>
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <input name="txtTopicName1" class="section-topic-field" type="text" onfocus="this.value=''" placeholder="topic name #1"/><br />
     </div>
    <!--<button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>-->
</form>
```

### The problem

However, the function ALWAYS triggers on the first input field, so typing ,for example, 4 letters in the first input field, will generate 4 input fields. And when you then type something in the actual last input field (the 4th in this case) nothing happens. So for some reason `$('.section-topic-field').last()` always selects the first input field.

I also tried the `:last` selector and the `:last-child`, but result is just the same

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: why are binding it on keyup.You can trigger it on blur.

Comment: what do you mean by _instead of just triggering on the last input field_ ?

Comment: why arnt you getting the last input field by its id..??

Comment: @pXL With _instead of just triggering on the last input field_, I mean that because of the `.last()` function, the even `keyup` should only fire on the last input field added? Should it not? (I'm fairly new to JQuery)

@AmitSharma I thought this should work aswell? And thought this was a cleaner solution (if it worked ;c), how would you get it by it's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the `input` dynamically I suggest you use `.on()`.

```
var i = $('.form-inputs input').size() + 1;

$('.form-inputs').on('keyup', '.section-topic-field:last', function (e) {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        var html_new_field = '<input name="txtTopicName' + i + '" class="section-topic-field" type="text" onfocus="this.value=\'\'" placeholder="topic name #' + i + '" /><br />';
        $('.form-inputs').append($(html_new_field).fadeIn('slow'));
        i++;
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/XHpXy/)

Unfortunately I'm not good at explaining but here you can find a short summary for the `on()` method. [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814409/2220391);

As said in the answer above

```
$("static selector").on('click', "dynamic selector", fn);
```

Given the parameters above, the `on()` method will search for the `dynamic selector` in the `static selector` when it is focused, clicked etc..

Using it like

```
$("static selector").on('click', fn);
```

Will work like a normal `.click()`

Comment: Thanks alot! This was indeed the solution I was looking for! :)

Comment: _"I suggest you use `.on()`"_ - You and I know why your code fixes the problem, but were you going to explain it for the OP? Especially given that `.on()` doesn't always handle dynamic elements, it depends on the parameters you pass it...

Comment: So, what does fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation (and the one in the link) were perfect :), thanks alot! All of you!

Answer (score 0):

It's creating a new field each time you have a keyup event - it's not linked to :last. I'm not sure how to fix it but `if($(this).val() != "")` doesn't work there so each new character entered will trigger one more field. How about using  `$('.section-topic-field').change(function() { ...});` instead?

Comment: Changing it to ` $('.section-topic-field').change(function() { ...});` does not work either, the problem is still the same, it always selects the first input field.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding an event listener to the last field **that exists on document ready** - which is actually the first (and only) field. This event listener stays on that exact field for the duration of its existence, or until you unbind the listener.

Remember, you are **not** running the whole of your quoted code every time a key is lifted, only the function you pass to the listener.

You need the following logical flow:

1. Create the first input element
2. Bind an event listener to that element once the user has stopped tying* which will create a new element if the current one is not empty
3. When that event fires:

   - create a new input element
   - unbind the original listener you created in 2
   - bind a new listener to the new input element (with the same functionality)

*`keyup` is not a good event to bind to in this case, because this will trigger as soon as the user types the first letter. You should probably consider instead using `blur`, or  waiting some number of seconds before triggering the event (see `setTimeout`). Alternatively you could use a button for the user to explicitly request a new input field?

Let me know if you need some examples.

Comment: I thought about doing something like this :), yet I thought to myself that it had to be simpler than that with the "last" selector, thanks for your reply! :)