# jQuery doesn't work with elements created after document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created two elements dinamically with jQuery:

a picture
and a Close button

I wrote the code to remove both in doument.ready function:

```
$( ".deletepreview" ).click(function() {
    code = $(this).data("prevcode");
    $('#'+code).remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

But it doesn't work, and I think this is because the code doesn't search in the code created after the document load.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: See other similar answers: [Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409) and [jQuery .on() method for adding a click event after loading dynamic html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use delegated events via [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you want events to be handled on dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletepreview",function() {
  var code = $(this).data("prevcode");
  $('#'+code).remove();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

I slightly modified your example: always declare variables with `var` in closures except when you need to.

Comment: one million dollar answer thanks mate you saved my day

Answer (score 8):

For dynamically created elements try using delegation with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.deletepreview', function() {
  var code = $(this).data('prevcode');
  $('#'+code).remove();
  $(this).remove();
});
```