# jquery events not working after dynamically adding elements with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

its weird that all my jquery events turn unresponsive after a ajax call. Im a load function call and once the jsp reloads all the events just do not respond. any help ?

the following is the code which triggers the function call.

```
$('#personTypeId').on('change', function() {
    var selectId = document.getElementById("personTypeId").value;
    if (selectId == 1 || selectId == 4 || selectId == 8) {
        $("#directoryFilter").load("directory/filters #directoryFilter",{"selectId" : selectId  });

    }
});
```

Comment: look at [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: i tried. but could not figure where im going wrong

Comment: can you share a sample event handler which is not triggering

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) for how to use the delegated version of `.on()`.

Comment: you need to do something like `$("#directoryFilter").on('event-name', 'target-eleement-selector', function(){})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny ...$('#subFilter').on({
  'click' : persons.loadFilterDropdown,
 });   this is one of the events not triggering

Comment: so as a other shared link has shown you.. you need to use `$("#directoryFilter").on('change', '#subFilter', function(){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("change", "#personTypeId", function(){
    var selectId = document.getElementById("personTypeId").value;
    if (selectId == 1 || selectId == 4 || selectId == 8) {
            $("#directoryFilter").load("directory/filters #directoryFilter",{"selectId" : selectId  });
    }
});
```

Comment: i want the a on change event to trigger for the selector #personTypeid but in the example you showed we are not even mentioning it. Im a bit new to jquery. correct me if im wrong. sorry

Comment: `$(document).on("change", "#directoryFilter", function(){
  /* Your code goes here..*/
});`

Comment: thanks, but my question was where are we defining the selector for the corresponding id

Comment: Please see the update answer, I have written the whole code for you. Hope this helps.

Comment: use parseInt("selectedId") to compare two integer values..!