# Add event dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, events, dynamic

I have the follow code in a js file:

```
    $(".dropmenu").on("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle();
    });
```

And i have the follow code in my webpage:

```
var append="<ul>";

$.each(items, function(i, v){
  append += "<li><a class='dropmenu' href='#'> Option </a>" +
              "<ul>" +
                 "<li><a href='somelink'>somelink</a></li>" +
              "</ul></li>";

}

$("div").append(append);
```

The point is when my ul tag its filled, the click event doesn't fire. I think because the class into anchor is dynamic.

How can I add the click event after the append function?

Comment: See how delegated event handling works to solve the issue of dynamically created elements: [Adding a click event for dynamic html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht/8752376#8752376) and [Does jQuery.on() work for elements that are added after the event handler is created?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this  [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used for delegation. Using `.delegate()` is an alternative.

As your `<ul>` element is getting appended dynamically, you have to delegate the event using `$(document)` of any other static parent element.

```
$(document).on('click','.dropmenu', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mF8bu/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for attaching events to dynamically added DOM.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
 $("body").on('click','.dropmenu', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: You need to bind it to a different element, the `ul` is also added dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa, your answer is much better

Comment: @elchente23: Actually I didn't post any answer to this question. It was closed when I looked at it.

Answer (score -1):

do you put your code in `$(document).ready`  i put it into and its working fine
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankchaturvedi/8ELuG/1/)

Comment: it's working for you cause you attached the click event after appending the elements... that means the element is present already :D