# jQuery Multiplication of Textbox Event Handler for Dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working multiplication of textbox, however, when I added a new textbox, the function will not performed. Only the first textboxes is being executed of the js function that I made. Sorry for asking this but I am pretty new to jsquery/javascript.

here's my working script: [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L17xoch7/)

```
What it does is, I have a table and 2 TR on it. it multiply the cost(3rd td) and the quantity(fourth td) and send the results to the line total (fifth td). Then I have a button, that will add another set of tr to the existing table, however, the multiplication wont work on the newly added tr.
```

Can you help me here?

TIA,

Nimitz

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these two lines as two last lines of your .click(...) handler:

```
$(".qty :input").off('keyup',byPrice).on('keyup',byPrice)
$(".price :input").off('keyup',byQty).on('keyup',byQty);
```

Here is updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/L17xoch7/1/)

The reason for that is - you have to re-register event listeners for the line newly created.
You can use same selectors, but then you have to "off" previous event listeners.

**Update**

Another approach, is you can bind events only on newly created row:
Here is another [JSFiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/jevgenig/L17xoch7/2/)

You have to put contents of newly created row into some variable:

```
$('#myinvoice tr:last').after($newRow = $('<tr><td>...'));
```

And then add events for the selectors inside this $newRow only:

```
$(".qty :input",$newRow).keyup(byPrice);
$(".price :input",$newRow).keyup(byQty);
```

I'd use second