# Click a span that was generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, events, dynamic

I edited a string in the following way, wrapping it using 2 numers with a span with a class.
After that, i would like to do some actions after the click on an element that has that class.
The following code doesn't work. Why?

```
var str="Hello, how are you?";
var start=2;
var end=5;
str=wrap(str,start,end);

$("#somewhere").html(str);

$(".blue").on("click",function(){
    alert("done");
});

function wrap(str,start,end) {
    var sx=str.substring(0,start);
    var wr=str.substring(start,end);
    var dx=str.substring(end,str.length);
    var ret=sx+"<span class='blue'>"+wr+"</span>"+dx;
    return(ret);
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown is just a string.  It's not inserted into the DOM where it would be clickable.  And, you have to run the `$(".blue").on(...)` after it's inserted into the DOM or switch to using [delegated event handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814298/does-jquery-on-work-for-elements-that-are-added-after-the-event-handler-is-cre/9814409#9814409).

Comment: I forgot to insert a string in the code: see now please.

Comment: After it's inserted in to the DOM the given answer will work

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tyx8t9L6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.blue' , function(){})
```

take a look at [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)